# insert query on few columns gives error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

My client is having a website who wants to transfer on our linux server. So I have set up all the files and database and now site is running fine on our development server.

Now when I try to `add to cart` then it gives the following error:
`Insert Operation Failed. Field UserID does not have default value`.
 Here is the INSERT CODE :

`$SQL="insert into cart set ProductID='some value',Amount='some value',Image='some value',SessionID='some value',Total='some value',ItemName='some value',Qty='some value'";`

```
`$rsSelect=$objDB->insert($SQL);`
```

In the table Name `CART` there are all the fields which is `NOT NULL` and few columns having the `DEFAULT VALUE` Set.

I understand what this error means but MY QUESTION IS :

Why can't this error comes on the live site or on my local system(localhost). And Why this error coming on my development server having database structure same on all the 3 servers?

Please Guide!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the row is actually inserted on the servers where it "works"? It may be that the error happens in all 3 places, but you can only *see* it on the dev box because of the error reporting settings (which is good, because that's how it should be set up). There are only 2 possibilities really: that ^^ or that the database isn't actually set up the same on all 3 servers.

Comment: Yes ! It is working fine on my local system and on live site but gives error on my linux development server. So you mean to say due to error reporting settings the errro is hidden from both the working servers?

Comment: database setup means ? database structure is different? No, structure is same throughout. And in your suggestion you are pointing on 2 possibilities - can you please explain me the first possibility. I am unable to get it.

Comment: Yes, what I'm suggesting is that possibly the error occurs everywhere, but the working servers just don't show it to you. You can easily test this - just put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script on one of the working servers, and see if you get the same error. If you do, then the problem happens everywhere, if you don't the then problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: In my config file there it is on top `ini_set("error_reporting","ALL");`
   `error_reporting("E_ALL");` but when removing these line on my local system gives several warnings and error. And the same code is also on my development server. I am getting confused now.

Comment: Its not working. I have set these  `ini_set( "display_errors", "Off" );``error_reporting(0);` ..but not working. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

The insert syntax should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: If I have to change the syntax then I can have already changed it. But it is not only for a single file or table. This issue is happening for many tables and pages. And things are working fine on live site and on my localhost system BUT NOT ON MY DEVELOPMENT SERVER. Please suggest if any other option.

Comment: Actually `INSERT ... SET` is a lesser used syntax but (certainly in MySQL) it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Not found any method to resolve my issue except to set the default value as per the requirement in my database for those columns which are not being used in the sql queries.

Thank you soo much guys for taking up time in it !